# Is there a way to access the package info from Ballerina.toml (org, name or version) in code?

Tags: ballerina

I'm trying to read the details from `Ballerina.toml` in code.

e.g. given the following, how can I access the name value from a module `.bal` file?

```
[package]
org = "myOrg"
name = "pkg"
version = "0.1.0"
```

Comment: These are meta-information related to a Ballerina package. Hence they cannot be accessed in a source `.bal`. Can you explain the requirement to access the package name in a source .bal file?

Comment: I need to tag some data with the version of the package they were generated on. Accessing the version of the running package/binary is a common requirement. Many frameworks have a way to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

Ballerina does not have a lang API to get the current module information. I have created an issue and started a discussion to support it. : https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/31018